# How do I decompile this Lua bytecode?

Tags: lua, hex, bytecode, decompiling

So I have some Lua bytecode, and now I would like to re-compile it into human readable code:

```
\27\76\117\97\81\0\1\4\8\4\8\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\2\2\4\0\0\0\5\0\0\0\65\64\0\0\28\64\0\1\30\0\128\0\2\0\0\0\4\6\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\112\114\105\110\116\0\4\9\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\72\105\32\116\104\101\114\101\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0
```

How would I achieve this? I have tried using LuaDec, but I get the following error:

> bad header in precompiled chunk

If anyone could help me that would be excellent.

Comment: It seems like the Lua was encoded using this:
https://github.com/JustAPerson/lbi/blob/master/src/lbi.lua

Answer (score 10):

**Step 1**
Write your bytecode into a file

```
local str = '\27\76\117\97\81\0\1\4\8\4\8\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\2\2\4\0\0\0\5\0\0\0\65\64\0\0\28\64\0\1\30\0\128\0\2\0\0\0\4\6\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\112\114\105\110\116\0\4\9\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\72\105\32\116\104\101\114\101\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0'
local file = io.open("bytecode.lua", "wb")
file:write(str)
file:close()
```

**Step 2**
Install Lua 5.1 (see lua.org for details)

**Step 3**
Run luac to view the content of bytecode

```
$ ~/lua-5.1.5/src/luac -l -l -p bytecode.lua

main <?:0,0> (4 instructions, 16 bytes at 0x19fd550)
0+ params, 2 slots, 0 upvalues, 0 locals, 2 constants, 0 functions
    1   [-] GETGLOBAL   0 -1    ; print
    2   [-] LOADK       1 -2    ; "Hi there"
    3   [-] CALL        0 2 1
    4   [-] RETURN      0 1
constants (2) for 0x19fd550:
    1   "print"
    2   "Hi there"
locals (0) for 0x19fd550:
upvalues (0) for 0x19fd550:
```

**Step 4**
Convert bytecode instructions manually into Lua source text :-)

```
print("Hi there")
```

Decompilation complete.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but I still get the same error: luac: bytecode.lua: bad header in precompiled chunk

Comment: Make sure you saved your bytecode correctly.  SHA256 of `bytecode.lua` file is `c0189615b...`